# Create a desktop shortcut for a group of bookmarked tabs in Firefox?

Tags: windows, firefox

Is there a way to create a desktop shortcut to a group of bookmarked tabs in Firefox?

To explain further: creating a desktop shortcut to a bookmark is easy - at the simplest you can just drag the url to the desktop.  And, bookmarking a group of tabs in Firefox is easy - just "Bookmark All Tabs", which you can then open all at once.

But - I can't seem to find a way to make a desktop bookmark to open a group of bookmarks in tabs at once.  Is my google-fu really bad, or is that actually not possible?

*(For the record, I'm on windows, but for the sake of completeness, answers on any and all platforms are welcome.)*

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Create a new shortcut to point to Firefox (or just copy an existing one).  Right-click on the shortcut and select "Properties".  In the "Target" field, scroll to the end of the line after the path to the firefox executable and add urls, each enclosed in quotes like this:

```
"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" "http://example.com" "http://superuser.com"
```

That should open each URL in a new tab.  Also check out the [Mozilla Knowledgebase](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Command_line_arguments) for more Firefox command line goodness.

**Update**:  Guess I should close my browser to test before declaring victory... updated with working answer on FF 3.5 on Win 7 x64

Comment: On FF3.5, on Win7, that's not working. It's opening up a new window for each site. I played with the -new-tab feature for several minutes, and it always opened new windows instead of tabs -- UNLESS Firefox was already running. If FF was already running, it opened new tabs within the most recently opened window.

Comment: Edit works beautifully; WAY better than my answer.

Comment: Slick!  Works perfect with 3.5 on my WinXP MCE box.

Comment: There seems to be a limit as to how many sites you can add? I tried to add about 10, I only was able to fit about 2 and a half.

Answer (score 1):

This assumes that you are (a) on Windows and (b) that Firefox is your default web browser.

Open up Notepad and type the following:

```
@echo off
start "superuser" "www.superuser.com"
start "google" "www.google.com"
```

Add more "start" lines as appropriate. Save this with the extension ".cmd", EG, "sites.cmd".

Create a shortcut to that and launch from there. That seems to reliably open one window with one tab for each site.

Ugly, but it works in 3.5 on Win7.

**UPDATE**

If you're on Windows, go with [heavyd's answer](https://superuser.com/questions/27490/create-a-desktop-shortcut-for-a-group-of-bookmarked-tabs-in-firefox/27499#27499) instead. You may have to adjust the path to Firefox (EG, mine is located in "Program Files (x86)"), but otherwise that's the cleanest way.

For now I'll leave this answer up, but I may delete it in the future if it proves to be too much noise.

Comment: Actually, that's a pretty cool hack.  I'd leave it up, personally - if for no other reason than I didn't know about the "start" command.