# Can I have an internet shortcut launch two pages?

Tags: web, shortcuts

I have an internet shortcut on my desktop.  It launches to a video streaming site I like to use.  This same site needs a java applet running in a separate window or tab.  Right now I just have two internet shortcuts - one for the site, one for the applet page.

Is there a way to have one shortcut open up both pages?

Either separate pages or separate tabs would be fine.

Thanks.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/27490/create-a-desktop-shortcut-for-a-group-of-bookmarked-tabs-in-firefox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Paste this into a text file, modify the URLs (and the browser directory if necessary), and save it as yourFileName.bat:

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" "http://www.google.com" "http://www.yahoo.com"

Mind the spaces.

Comment: keep the quotes?

Comment: Works awesome.  Very useful.  I assume I could create batch files to open any program?

Comment: Quotes on the command line serve to concatenate arguments - not needed here, as URLs should always be spaceless. (For example, firefox.exe foo bar would open firefox and try to open foo and bar, but firefox.exe "foo bar" would try to open foo bar.)

Comment: Good point. I just put quotes around the program directory and then the URLs out of habit. In any case, they don't hurt.

Answer (score 2):

I am using firefox on linux, and the command line

```
firefox www.google.co.uk www.google.fr
```

works for me to open a web browser with those two pages.

You don't say what operating  system / browser you are using but I'm sure that a desktop launcher/shortcut with a command based on that format would work.

In Windows XP, right click on  the desktop, select New-> Shortcut, enter

```
"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"  www.google.co.uk www.google.fr
```

Answer (score 0):

How about a shortcut to a batch file that opens both?